# How to solve link Posts and users to comments in Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to link each comment to a post and to a username

I have proceeded with the logic of the comment with the following `models.py`

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

Now that the comment is working and everything I am trying to link the comment section to the post and the user of the comment in the admin so I used the following `models.py`

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=160)


    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.post.title, str(self.user.username)) <----Error line
```

Which is returning

```
AttributeError at /admin/score/comment/ 
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'
```

What should fix this problem
I have also used the following which did not work

```
    def __str__(self):
       return '%s %s' % (self.post.title, self.user.username)
```

Comment: It looks like there is at least one instance of Comment created which does not have a post entry (which you allow via `null=True, blank=True`). Therefore, `self.post.title` tries to access the Attribute of `None`, raising the error you see.
You could set `null=False` which will raise an error when trying to generate the Comment without a post.

Comment: Actually your comment helped me solve it as I realized I just had to delete the post or even that I allowed the null db and start over, post it as an answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is at least one instance of Comment created which does not have a post entry (which you allow via `null=True, blank=True`). Therefore, `self.post.title` tries to access the Attribute `title` of `None`, raising the error you see. You could set `null=False` which will raise an error when trying to generate the Comment without a post.